# Updating Heroku Buildpack to use ffmpegthumbnailer 2.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku, ffmpeg, buildpack

The app I am working on is currently using a buildpack that is using ffmpegthumbnailer 2.0.8 and I need a feature that was added in version 2.1.2. I have forked the repo of the buildpack we are currently using https://github.com/akomic/heroku-buildpack-ffmpegthumbnailer and updated the `bin/compile` file to point the download_url to "https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/archive/2.2.0.tar.gz" but when I add my forked repo to the app and run `heroku run "ffmpegthumbnailer -version"` to verify that it worked I get a `bash: ffmpegthumbnailer: command not found` error.

Here is the original `bin/compile`:

```
#!/bin/sh

indent() {
  sed -u 's/^/       /'
}

echo "-----> Install ffmpegthumbnailer"
BUILD_DIR=$1
VENDOR_DIR="vendor"
DOWNLOAD_URL="http://www.aksiom.net/stuff/ffmpegthumbnailer_2.0.8-2.bin.tar.gz"

echo "DOWNLOAD_URL = " $DOWNLOAD_URL | indent

cd $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $VENDOR_DIR
cd $VENDOR_DIR
curl -L --silent $DOWNLOAD_URL | tar zx

echo "exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH" | indent
PROFILE_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/.profile.d/ffmpeg.sh"
mkdir -p $(dirname $PROFILE_PATH)
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer_2.0.8-2/bin"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer_2.0.8-2/lib"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
```

Here is my updated bin/compile in the forked repo:

```
#!/bin/sh

indent() {
  sed -u 's/^/       /'
}

echo "-----> Install ffmpegthumbnailer"
BUILD_DIR=$1
VENDOR_DIR="vendor"
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/archive/2.2.0.tar.gz"

echo "DOWNLOAD_URL = " $DOWNLOAD_URL | indent

cd $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $VENDOR_DIR
cd $VENDOR_DIR
curl -L --silent $DOWNLOAD_URL | tar zx

echo "exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH" | indent
PROFILE_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/.profile.d/ffmpeg.sh"
mkdir -p $(dirname $PROFILE_PATH)
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer_2.0.8-2/bin"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/vendor/ffmpegthumbnailer_2.0.8-2/lib"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
```

Other info: I add the buildpack using `heroku buildpacks:add <link_to_forked_repo>`

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same exact thing. Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the original akomic tarball specified is not the source code, but rather a custom zip of compiled binaries and libraries. Notice that the `compile` script has no `make` step, for instance. There is no documentation for how this custom tarball created, but presumably if you go through the same process with a newer version of the source code, and then upload it to a place this script can access it, it will work again. I'm trying to figure this out now.